# Why doesnt next() work in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I cannot work out why i cannot pick up the next list item in jquery. However, I can pick up the the span tag after the p tag. Why is this? Please do not just quote me the jquery manual, because I am obviously not understanding it. Thanks in advance.

```
<ul>
    <li id="one" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">1<li>
    <li id="two" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">2<li>
    <li id="three" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">3<li>
    <li id="four" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">4<li>
    <li id="five" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">5<li>
</ul>

<div class="div">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <span>Bye</span>
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#two').next().css('color','red');
    $('.div p').css('color','red');
});
```

**EDIT: My li tags are not closed. That is causing the problem**

Comment: Your code has syntax error, unbalanced parenthesis, so it isn't doing anything at all

Comment: Thanks changed that. Still got my problem though

Comment: Add a class EmptyClass to each of your <li> and write $('#two').next('.EmptyClass').css('color', 'red');

Comment: The li end tags should be `</li>`, not `<li>`. You have every other list item empty and the `.next()` selects one of those.

Comment: @Juhana that was the problem, thanks

Comment: li elements are not properly closed still. <li> ... </li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `li` elements are missing the '/' at the end: `</li>` <-- CORRECT

Comment: Can you explain? Also I only want the next one, not all of them

Comment: Thanks, it was the ending </li> that was the problem. Thanks all

Comment: @Esailija you are right, once that was fixed, it all worked anyway but +1 for Roko for spotting it

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close `li` tags (I've fixed)

```
<ul>
    <li id="one" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">1</li>
    <li id="two" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">2</li>
    <li id="three" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">3</li>
    <li id="four" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">4</li>
    <li id="five" style="display:block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: lightgrey; margin:4px;">5</li>
</ul>

<div class="div">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <span>Bye</span>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#two').next().css('color','red');
    $('.div p').css('color','red');
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/DF4C7/)

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing your `li` tags, but opening new ones. Therefore the next `li` you are selecting is an empty one and not the one that's visible, so you see no result

So you're doing `<li>...<li>` which ends in (after the browser parses your HTML):

```
<li id="one">1</li>
<li></li>
<li id="two">2</li>
<li></li>                 <-- this one is selected
<li id="three">3/<li>
```

Solution is to close the tags correctly `<li>...</li>`.